# Connecting to water line stubs left at construction

Tags: plumbing, sink, utilities

I'm looking to install a utility sink on my patio that already has water lines that are capped off by the builders. If I am correct there is also a capped off drain pipe available. Are the water lines in the picture pex pipes? If so, do I just cut off the end caps to connect fittings? I appreciate any additional help on the best way to install my utility sink to the lines below. thx!

[image]

Comment: I guess you don't live in a place that freezes?  Those exposed pipes would be an issue otherwise.

Comment: Where I live, you drain all the outdoor taps every fall.   He could do the same.  But if he forgot....BIG TROUBLE!

Comment: You might want to verify that that's a hookup for a sink and not a hookup for some sort of heat recovery system. that looks like weird plumbing for a sink.

Comment: Correct, down here in South Florida freezing temperatures are definitely not an issue.

Comment: Why do you say that's weird, Jack? Looks standard to me. 1-1/2" drain, 1/2" supplies.

Comment: @isherwood  I've just never seen  plumbing for a sink to be installed on a patio done by a builder.  It's standard fittings but a strange location....

Answer (score 2):

All looks fine to me. 1-1/2" drain, 1/2" supplies. Just turn off the water at the appropriate point and cut off all three caps. I'm not sure what the sleeves are for over the supplies, but I'd remove them.

Don't forget to put a standard sink drain trap in to block sewer gases.

Comment: The sleeves over the stubs are likely to block UV from sunlight, which degrades the strength of PEX very quickly.

Comment: Good point. They probably won't be necessary after the sink is in place.

Comment: The OP asked if the pipes are pex so they probably do not know how to work with pex.   I think the they would like to know how to connect to pex. ( I.E.  crimp pex fittings with special tools or compression fittings and how to do either. )

Comment: Special tools are not needed to connect to pex, but the fittings are more expensive. still cheaper than the tools though.

Comment: I consider a tutorial on working with pex to be too broad for SE. There are volumes on the subject already written elsewhere.